# Click to call with different images for different sized browsers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bit of code that changes my logo on the mobile to a Click To Call image otherwise on all other sizes it's just a regular logo with no click to call feature.  However I can't seem to get it to actually click to call. It does change the logo on the mobile size but it won't click to call.  It does nothing when you click it. What I'm I doing wrong here?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" align="center">
      <a href="tel:8003220503">
        <img src="../mobile/Acrictc.png" class="btn-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image"></a>
      <!--Mobile     <img src="../mobile/Acrictc.png" class="img-responsive"alt="image" /> -->
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg" align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="../pics/AcriLogoBlue.jpg" width="220" height="120" alt="" />
      <!--Tab-->
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 hidden-lg" align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="../pics/AcriLogoBlue.jpg" width="220" height="120" alt="" />
      <!--Desktop-->
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-3" align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="../pics/AcriLogoBlue.jpg" width="220" height="120" alt="" />
      <!--Large-->
    </div>

    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-5 col-lg-5" align="center">
      <p>
        <font color="#000080">Windows - Siding - Roofing - Bathroom Remodeling - Patio Spaces</font>
      </p>
      <a align="center"><h1><strong><font color="red">800-322-0503</font></strong></h1></a>
      <p>
        <font color="#000080">Quality Products at Unbelievable Prices - Since 1967</font>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
      <span class="visible-lg"></span>
      <img src="http://acricompany.com/pics/fpq2.gif" width="220" height="120" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that the very bottom `<div>` (the `fpq2.gif`) only has a class of `col-md-3`, which at smaller sizes is causing it to overlap the image above for some reason (didn't look into it). Add `col-xs-12` and any other required classes to that `div` and your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, know that there are such classes as `visible-md` and `visible-xs`. They save a lot of code and improve readability. Note that these classes are called `hidden-*-up` and `hidden-*-down` in Twitter Bootstrap 4 (where * stands for the size).

Secondly, note that SVG is supported really well these days, see: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg. You just might want to use that for your logo. SVG renders perfect on any size. This will drastically reduce the amount of images you need. You might end up with a 'click me' image with a visible-xs class and a regular one with an hidden-xs class.

Last of all, please note that looking at the rendered size of the page (which is done by Twitter Bootstrap) is not an acurate way (anymore) to determine the amount of pixels you need for your image, due to retina displays. A visible-xs class image might actually need more pixels to be perfectly sharp than an image with a hidden-xs class. Please read this article: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/08/the-state-of-responsive-images/ (or a similar one).